# .app extension in folder with .service ending

Tags: macos, filesystem

I cloned a git repository and there's a folder with `.service` ending, so my Mac adds the `.app` extension. How can I disable it, because I simply can operate with that?

[image: Screenshot of a git repository that had the .service extension renamed to a .app extension]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, when you clone the repository, macOS changes the .service extension to .app and you’re wanting to change it back to .service?